# Tab Screens in Custom Bottom Navigator displaying over other Screens where the Custom Bottom Navigator is imported in React Native

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, react-native-navigation

I am implementing a custom bottom navigator in React Native having four screens(Home,Category,Profile and Cart) in my App.However,I am encountering a problem when I import the custom bottom navigator to a screen called TestScreen.The Tab Screens are displayed but now the content on each active Tab Screen clicked in the custom bottom navigator displays over the content of TestScreen giving the page a very unprofessional look.I needed the Tab screens in the Bottom Navigator to appear without overwriting on the contents of the TestScreen.I could solve it by including the TestScreen among the Tab Screens in the custom bottom navigator but doing that will mean I have five Tab screens instead of four as per the figma design.How do I solve this challenge?

Below is the screenshot illustrating what I am experiencing.
**screenshot** [image: screenshot]

Here is the code for Custom Bottom Navigator

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import HomeScreen from '../../../screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../../../screens/ProfileScreen';
import CategoryScreen from '../../../screens/CategoryScreen';
import CartScreen from '../../../screens/CartScreen';
import Products from '../Products';
import SearchScreen from '../../../screens/SearchScreen';
import { Colors } from '../../../src/components/consts/Colors';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomNavigator = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const [cartTotalProducts, setCartTotalProducts] = useState(0);


  useEffect(() => {

  }, [isFocused]);

  return isFocused ? (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  
          screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'orange' },
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'orange',
      }}> 

    <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color = 'orange' }) => (
            <Icon name="home-filled" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Categories"
        component={CategoryScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="list" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="person" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={CartScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="shopping-cart" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
          
          tabBarVisible: true,
        }}
      />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  ) : (
    <View />
  );
};

export default BottomNavigator;
```

And this is the code in App.Js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen'
import SecondScreen from './screens/SecondScreen';
import ScannerScreen from './screens/ScannerScreen';
import ThirdScreen from './screens/ThirdScreen';
import SkipButton from './screens/SkipButton';
import AddPhotoScreen from './screens/AddPhotoScreen';
import SocialMediaScreen from './screens/SocialMediaScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from './screens/ForgotPasswordScreen';
import ResetPasswordScreen from './screens/ResetPasswordScreen';
import InterestsScreen from './screens/InterestsScreen';
import OnboardScreen from './screens/OnboardScreen';
import BottomNavigator from './src/components/navigation/BottomNavigator';
import CollectRewardScreen from './screens/CollectRewardScreen';
import GoalScreen from './screens/GoalScreen';
import PhotoUploadScreen from './screens/PhotoUploadScreen';
import Products from './src/components/Products';
import CategoryScreen from './screens/CategoryScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';
import PasswordResetSuccess from './screens/PasswordResetSuccess';
import OrderScreen from './screens/OrderScreen';
import CartDetailScreen from './screens/CartDetailScreen';
import CustomTabBar from './src/components/navigation/CustomTabBar';
import FlashMessage from "react-native-flash-message";
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
import TestScreen from './screens/TestScreen';





const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {

  const [cartTotalProducts, setCartTotalProducts] = useState(0);
  LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(); //Ignore all log notifications


  console.log('carttta' + cartTotalProducts)

  // const  


  return (

    <NavigationContainer>
      <FlashMessage position="top" />
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome">
        <Stack.Screen component={WelcomeScreen} name="Welcome" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={BottomNavigator} name="Home" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={HomeScreen} name="First" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={SecondScreen} name="Second" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={ThirdScreen} name="Third" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={ScannerScreen} name="Scanner" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={SkipButton} name="Skip" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={CollectRewardScreen} name="Collect" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={AddPhotoScreen} name="Pic" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={SocialMediaScreen} name="Socials" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={SignupScreen} name="Signup" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={LoginScreen} name="Login" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={ForgotPasswordScreen} name="Fgetpwd" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={ResetPasswordScreen} name="Reset" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={OnboardScreen} name="Onboard" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={InterestsScreen} name="Interests" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={GoalScreen} name="Goals" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={PhotoUploadScreen} name="Upload" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={Products} name="Myproducts" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={CategoryScreen} name="Category" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={ProductScreen} name="Pdsn" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
         <Stack.Screen component={CartScreen } name="Cart" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={PasswordResetSuccess} name="ResetSuccess" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={OrderScreen} name="Order" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={CartDetailScreen} name="Details" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={CustomTabBar} name="CustBar" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen component={TestScreen} name="Test" options={{ headerShown: false }} />

      
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And finally code for the TestScreen

```
import React from 'react'

import { View, Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import BottomNavigator from '../src/components/navigation/BottomNavigator'

const TestScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        padding: 16,}} >
    <View>

        <Text>Test Screen</Text>
        <Text>Test Screen where my Tabscreens (Home,Categories,Profile and Cart) are appearing.This makes the screen looks unprofessional.</Text>

    </View>
    <BottomNavigator />
    </View>
  )
}
 


export default TestScreen
```

I tried creating another customTabBar renaming the screen name to First but nothing changed at all.

Here is the code for CustomTabBar

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import HomeScreen from '../../../screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../../../screens/ProfileScreen';
import CategoryScreen from '../../../screens/CategoryScreen';
import CartScreen from '../../../screens/CartScreen';
import Products from '../Products';
import SearchScreen from '../../../screens/SearchScreen';
import { Colors } from '../consts/Colors';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const CustomTabBar = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const [cartTotalProducts, setCartTotalProducts] = useState(0);


  useEffect(() => {
    // any necessary logic to be executed when the screen is focused
  }, [isFocused]);

  return isFocused ? (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="First"  
          screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'orange' },
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'orange',
      }}> 

    <Tab.Screen
        name="First"
        component={HomeScreen}
        tabLabel="Home"
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color = 'orange' }) => (
            <Icon name="home-filled" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Categories"
        component={CategoryScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="list" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="person" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={CartScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="shopping-cart" color={color} size={28} />
          ),
          // set tabBarVisible to false for screens where you don't want the bottom navigators to appear
          tabBarVisible: true,
        }}
      />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  ) : (
    <View />
  );
};

export default CustomTabBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For one to have Bottom Tabs in specific screens, you can nest those screens inside the ones included in the Bottom Tab. For example,to make SubCategory screen have  Bottom Tabs,nest it inside CategoryStackScreen. Inside CategoryStackScreen, set Category Screen as the initial route name, followed by SubCategory screen.Include CategoryStackScreen in the Bottom Tab Navigator and give it a Tab screen name. I believe this solves the problem.
Here is the illustration:


`
        import * as React from 'react';
        import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
        import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
        import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
        import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
    
    ';
    
    
    function CategoryScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Category screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to SubCategories"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SubCategory')}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    
    function SubCategoryScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>SubCategory screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Products"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyProducts')}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const CategoryStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
    function CategoryStackScreen() {
      return (
        <CategoryStack.Navigator>
          <CategoryStack.Screen name="Category" component={CategoryScreen} />
          <CategoryStack.Screen name="SubCategory" component={SubCategoryScreen} />
        </CategoryStack.Navigator>
      );
    }


`
Also,here is the link to the official react native documentation [A stack navigator for each tab][1].


  [1]: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).